# Making My JavaScript Into JQuery (Involves HTML Canvas)

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Newb here. I can't seem to turn this vanilla JS into working JQuery. Can I have a little help? It would be greatly appreciated. It would be nice if someone actually went through and fixed each line. I've tried to, to no avail.

```
window.onload = function(){

    "use strict";

    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var eyeColorControl = document.getElementById("eyeColor");
    var eyeSizeControl = document.getElementById("eyeSize");
    var sleepinessControl = document.getElementById("Sleepiness");
    var frownControl = document.getElementById("Frowniness");

    var smilex = canvas.width / 2;
    var smiley = canvas.height -60;
    var radiusS = 70;
    var startAngle = 1.1 * Math.PI;
    var endAngle = 1.9 * Math.PI;
    var counterClockwise = false;

    var eye1x = canvas.width / 4;
    var eye1Y = canvas.height / 3;
    var eye2x = canvas.width / 1.34;
    var eye2Y = canvas.height / 3;

    var radiusE = 70;
    var scaleY = 1;

    var newLineWidth = 5;

    var newFillStyle = context.fillStyle;

    document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }, false);

    document.getElementById("renderBtn").onclick = function() {draw();};

    function draw() 
    { 

        context.fillStyle = document.getElementById("eyeColor").value;
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(smilex, smiley, radiusS, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
        context.lineWidth = 5;
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.stroke();
        context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(eye1x, eye1Y, radiusE, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = newLineWidth;
        context.stroke();
        context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(eye2x, eye2Y, radiusE, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = newLineWidth;
        context.stroke();
        context.setTransform(1,0,0,scaleY,0,0);

    }

    draw();

    eyeSizeControl.onchange = function() 
    {
       radiusE = parseFloat(eyeSizeControl.value);
       draw();
    }

    sleepinessControl.onchange = function() 
    {
       newLineWidth = parseFloat(sleepinessControl.value);
       draw();
    }

    frownControl.onchange = function() 
    {
       scaleY = parseFloat(frownControl.value);
       draw();
    }

    eyeColorControl.onchange = function() 
    {
       newFillStyle = parseFloat(eyeColorControl.value);
       draw();
    }

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById('myCanvas').src = dataURL;

};
```

Comment: You need to describe what your problem is. What exactly are you trying to do? What is the expected output? What do you get instead?

Comment: This is an interactive HTML canvas whose attributes the user can edit using input fields. Here's the JS Fiddle:

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vdp24/

Comment: just need to make the javascript into jquery

Comment: There is a LOT of busy-work here. I can get you started with changing all "document.getElementById" commands to $('#theid').val() to input fields. .click functions can be changed to ('#button').on('click', function(){ put your function here });

Comment: It is worth noting that you probably don't want to change **all** of the document.getElementById methods to jQuery objects as you won't be able to use native DOM element methods like canvas.getContext('2d'); if it is a jQuery object. You **could** write var canvas = $('#myCanvas'); var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d'); - the [0] converts it back to a DOM element (or rather extracts the DOM element from the jQuery object), but this would be more than a bit wasteful in comparison to just selecting it using DOM methods to start with.